# Propagate values up a Data.Tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, functional-programming

Using `Data.Tree` I can define a tree like this:

```
mkTree :: T.Tree Double
mkTree = T.Node 0 [ T.Node 4 []
                  , T.Node 0 [T.Node 5 [], T.Node 4 []]
                  , T.Node 0 [T.Node 2 [], T.Node 1 []]
                  ]
```

Which would transfer to this:

```
0.0
|
+- 4.0
|
+- 0.0
|  |
|  +- 5.0
|  |
|  `- 4.0
|
`- 0.0
   |
   +- 2.0
   |
   `- 1.0
```

I now want to transform the tree so that each `T.Node` now contains the sum (or some other function) of its children:

```
16.0
|
+- 4.0
|
+- 9.0
|  |
|  +- 5.0
|  |
|  `- 4.0
|
`- 3.0
   |
   +- 2.0
   |
   `- 1.0
```

The problem is that I can't access the children of a node using `fmap`. What I have so far is these to functions:

```
propagate :: Num a => T.Tree a -> T.Tree a
propagate (T.Node x []) = T.Node x []
propagate (T.Node _ ts) = T.Node (sum $ map gather ts) (map propagate ts)

gather :: Num a => T.Tree a -> a
gather (T.Node n []) = n
gather (T.Node _ ts) = sum $ map gather ts
```

But that seems too complicated, especially if I were to replace `sum` with another function. Maybe there is a better way to do this using `Foldable` or `Traversable`?

Comment: You might like [dual-tree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dual-tree) (using the [`Sum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum) monoid as the upward-traveling annotation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `Foldable` exposes enough of a `Tree`'s structure to do what you want. `Traversable` might, but it seems relatively tricky to get right; I think I would prefer implementing a recursion pattern like this one:

```
foldTree :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
foldTree f = go where
    go (Node value children) = f value (map go children)
```

Then you can implement your summing operation as

```
sums :: Num a => Tree a -> Tree a
sums = foldTree (\val children -> Node (sum (val:map rootLabel children)) children)
```

or even generalize from `Num` to `Semigroup` using `sconcat` and `(:|)` in place of `sum` and `(:)`.

Comment: `Traversable` is definitely not sufficient. I think there's stuff for this in `uniplate`, but I've never used it. Your approach looks perfectly sensible.

Comment: Would you mind writing to libraries@haskell.org to propose adding that to `Data.Tree`? It's conspicuously missing.

Comment: @dfeuer It seems that `containers` is not maintained by libraries@; at least it isn't mentioned [on the wiki page about core libraries](https://wiki.haskell.org/Library_submissions) and the listed maintainer on Hackage changed away from libraries@ several major versions ago. That said, I've [filed a pull request](https://github.com/haskell/containers/pull/232).

Comment: As of a few weeks ago, I co-maintain `containers` with Wren Romano. Because of its privileged place in the package hierarchy, and its tremendous number of reverse dependencies, the previous maintainers of the package have established a tradition of consulting the libraries list about API changes. Some additions that particularly fit the rest of the API might get a pass, but this is the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 1):

You wish operate, for each node, with all subtree (node label included) then, one usefull function may be

```
subtrees :: Tree a -> Tree (Tree a)
subtrees n@(Node _ xs) = Node n (map subtrees xs)
```

now, you can apply any tree function to any tree of trees

```
sumSubtree :: Num a => Tree a -> Tree a
sumSubtree = fmap sum . subtrees
```

with the desired result.

As Daniel say, this `sumSubtree` is inefficient since sum from leafs to root have optimal substructure.

But then, not unique solution exists, look to the next fold version

```
foldTree :: (a → Forest b → b) → Tree a → Tree b
foldTree f (Node x xs) = Node (f x xs') xs'
                         where xs' = foldTree f ↥ xs
```

now is optimal only if `f` not need the root and previous branchs to compute some branch value (e.g. the sum problem). But (e.g.) if some key is stored on each node this sum implementation will be inefficient too.

(Using the previous fold, the sum problem may be written `foldTree (λx xs → ∑(x: map rootLabel xs))`)

Comment: ...but this is incredibly inefficient, as it will recompute sums of deep subtrees very often.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think that your assumption about `f` is wrong, "The problem is that I can't access the children of a node", the sum problem is an example, not the general case. You can optimize tail computations (the sum case) but then ignore preffix computations. I only have solved the suggested general problem.